# Is there some feature/bug surrounding the F5 (Refresh) shortcut in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide

Depending on which workspace I'm currently using and for all I know the position of the moon eclipse turns on and off the built in shortcut for refreshing (F5). If I look it up in the settings it's still set. Yet if I right-click on for example a project I see "Refresh" instead of the normal "Refresh (F5)".

Is anyone else having the same problem or am I an annoyingly unique snowflake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029286/f5-refresh-not-always-available-working-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any additional plugins installed? I guess there might be a conflict (if two plugins install the same shortcuts in the same context, none of them will work) Can you check the Error Log view for any warnings on the conflict?

Also see: 
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=205748
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=323959

Comment: Found the answer on that page, it's the debugger stealing the keybinding.

Answer (score 1):

The debugger’s Step Into wins over Refresh: Eclipse bug [246483](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=246483)

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on automatic refresh in Eclipse, then theoretically Refresh won't be required at all.
Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Refresh