# F5 refresh not always available/working in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Usually if I want to refresh a project (or folder, Working Set, ...) in eclipse I just select the project and hit <kbd>F5</kbd>. Sometimes however nothing happens after hitting <kbd>F5</kbd>. When I then right-click the project I see in the context menu the option `Refresh` and not `Refresh... (F5)`.

So for some reason the current state or such of the project does not allow <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh. I have this issue now in Indigo but this was already there in at least the 2 previous versions of eclipse.

Is this a bug or is there a (valid) reason why <kbd>F5</kbd> is sometimes not available?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess would be that the F5 key is mapped to multiple actions, where "Refresh" has the lowest priority. You can see the mapping under Preferences > General > Keys

By default F5 is mapped to "Refresh" and "Step into" while debugging, there can be more mappings depending on which plugins you use.

But in another note:

Even if the context menu lists F5 as shortcuts, refreshing often doesn't work for me that way (especially when I have an 'out-of-sync' error from CVS). I got used to rightclick refresh my project as it always works...

Comment: There are indeed 2 bindings for F5: Windows > Refresh and Debugging > Step into. Nothing is running and I'm not in the Debug perspective. I do not think it's related to CSS but I do have it often after the message 'Resource is out of sync' (which is of course a trigger to hit F5).

Comment: +1 If you have a debugging session going (even if it is in the background and you are in a different perspective) the F5 is disabled for refresh and mapped to "Step-Info".  Stopping the debug session will re-enable F5 for refresh.

Comment: Also see Eclipse bug [246483](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=246483) (from 2008)

Answer (score 15):

> So for some reason the current state or such of the project does not allow <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh.

If you have a **debugging session going** (even if it is in the background and you are in a different perspective) the <kbd>F5</kbd> is disabled for Refresh and mapped to "Step-Into".

Stopping the debug session will re-enable <kbd>F5</kbd> for Refresh.

Answer (score 1):

Check the GeForce Experience shortcuts, disable Alt + F5.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just leave this here in case it affects anyone.

If you are adding a file/folder but it's filtered out in Package Explorer > Filters , refreshing will work but obviously not show the added resource

This might look like a silent failure (it's not; it's doing what you asked, if only by default in some cases).